# Is there a way to fix an expression with operators in it after parsing, using a table of associativities and precedences?

Tags: parsing, haskell, operators, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm currently working on a parser for a simple programming language written in Haskell. I ran into a problem when I tried to allow for binary operators with differing associativities and precedences. Normally this wouldn't be an issue, but since my language allows users to define their own operators, the precedence of operators isn't known by the compiler until the program has already been parsed.

Here are some of the data types I've defined so far:

```
data Expr
  = Var String 
  | Op String Expr Expr
  | ..

data Assoc 
  = LeftAssoc 
  | RightAssoc 
  | NonAssoc

type OpTable = 
  Map.Map String (Assoc, Int)
```

At the moment, the compiler parses all operators as if they were right-associative with equal precedence. So if I give it an expression like `a + b * c < d` the result will be `Op "+" (Var "a") (Op "*" (Var "b") (Op "<" (Var "c") (Var "d")))`.

I'm trying to write a function called `fixExpr` which takes an `OpTable` and an `Expr` and rearranges the `Expr` based on the associativities and precedences listed in the `OpTable`. For example:

```
operators :: OpTable
operators =
  Map.fromList
    [ ("<", (NonAssoc, 4))
    , ("+", (LeftAssoc, 6))
    , ("*", (LeftAssoc, 7))
    ]

expr :: Expr
expr = Op "+" (Var "a") (Op "*" (Var "b") (Op "<" (Var "c") (Var "d")))
```

`fixExpr operators expr` should evaluate to `Op "<" (Op "+" (Var "a") (Op "*" (Var "b") (Var "c"))) (Var "d")`.

How do I define the `fixExpr` function? I've tried multiple solutions and none of them have worked.

Comment: Do you allow unary operators? Postfix operators? What some people call "distfix", or enclosing operators (e.g. subscripts or `let` expressions)? How do you know what an operator token is before operator token definitions are processed? But that's all a digression. If you can tokenise, the easiest solution is to do the initial parse into a simple token list (respecting parentheses if you are sure what those are) and then use operator precedence parsing aka "the shunting yard" to create the final AST. (If someone tells you that SY only produces postfix, they're talking through their hat.)

Comment: Include one of the solutions you've tried and describe why it didn't work.

Comment: N.B. you're going to need some way to differentiate the parses of `a * b + c` and `a * (b + c)`, even though both parses associate everything to the right. Consider parsing operator chains to lists; that way, the former is `Ops a [(*,b), (+,c)]` while the latter is `Ops a [(*, Ops b [(+,c)])]`, or something similar.

Comment: What parsing library are you using? You could probably generate new expression parsers dynamically with this: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-6.4.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Expr.html, but this might conflate the stages of your compiler a bit too much, since it forces your parser to calculate these tables instead doing it at a later stage.

Comment: GHC is using something similar to the method you are proposing and performs that step in the renamer https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/compiler/renamer. Here is the code. I don't yet fully understood how it works: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/blob/master/compiler/GHC/Rename/HsType.hs#L1283-1310

Comment: "the precedence of operators isn't known by the compiler until the program has already been parsed" So, in a way, the parser is a function of the parsed AST. Why don't go with that, and try to tie the knot? Something like `precedences :: AST -> OpTable`, `parse :: OpTable -> Text -> AST` and then `parse' text = let ast = parse (precedences ast) text in ast`.

Answer (score 2):

An expression *e* may be an atomic term *n* (e.g. a variable or literal), a parenthesised expression, or an application of an infix operator ○.

*e* ⩴ *n* | **(***e*​**)** | *e*<sub>1</sub> ○ *e*<sub>2</sub>

We need the parentheses to know whether the user entered *a* * *b* + *c*, which we happen to associate as *a* * (*b* + *c*) and need to reassociate as (*a* * *b*) + *c*, or if they entered *a* * **(***b* + *c***)** literally, which should not be reassociated. Therefore I’ll make a small change to the data type:

```
data Expr
  = Var String 
  | Group Expr
  | Op String Expr Expr
  | …
```

Then the method is simple:

1. The rebracketing of an expression ⟦*e*⟧ applies recursively to all its subexpressions.

   1. ⟦*n*⟧ = *n*
   2. ⟦**(***e***)**⟧ = **(**⟦*e*⟧**)**
   3. ⟦*e*<sub>1</sub> ○ *e*<sub>2</sub>⟧ = ⦅⟦*e*<sub>1</sub>⟧ ○ ⟦*e*<sub>2</sub>⟧⦆
2. A single reassociation step ⦅*e*⦆ removes redundant parentheses on the right, and reassociates nested operator applications leftward in two cases: if the left operator has higher precedence, or if the two operators have equal precedence, and are both left-associative. It leaves nested infix applications alone, that is, associating rightward, in the opposite cases: if the right operator has higher precedence, or the operators have equal precedence and right associativity. If the associativities are mismatched, then the result is undefined.

   1. ⦅*e* ○ *n*⦆ = *e* ○ *n*
   2. ⦅*e*<sub>1</sub> ○ **(***e*<sub>2</sub>**)**⦆ = ⦅*e*<sub>1</sub> ○ *e*<sub>2</sub>⦆
   3. ⦅*e*<sub>1</sub> ○ (*e*<sub>2</sub> ● *e*<sub>3</sub>)⦆ =

      1. ⦅*e*<sub>1</sub> ○ *e*<sub>2</sub>⦆ ● *e*<sub>3</sub>, if:

         a. P(○) > P(●); or

         b. P(○) = P(●) and A(○) = A(●) = **L**
      2. *e*<sub>1</sub> ○ (*e*<sub>2</sub> ● *e*<sub>3</sub>), if:

         a. P(○) < P(●); or

         b. P(○) = P(●) and A(○) = A(●) = **R**
      3. *undefined* otherwise

NB.: P(*o*) and A(*o*) are respectively the precedence and associativity (**L** or **R**) of operator *o*.

This can be translated fairly literally to Haskell:

```
fixExpr operators = reassoc
  where

    -- 1.1
    reassoc e@Var{} = e

    -- 1.2
    reassoc (Group e) = Group (reassoc e)

    -- 1.3
    reassoc (Op o e1 e2) = reassoc' o (reassoc e1) (reassoc e2)

    -- 2.1
    reassoc' o e1 e2@Var{} = Op o e1 e2

    -- 2.2
    reassoc' o e1 (Group e2) = reassoc' o e1 e2

    -- 2.3
    reassoc' o1 e1 r@(Op o2 e2 e3) = case compare prec1 prec2 of

      -- 2.3.1a
      GT -> assocLeft

      -- 2.3.2a
      LT -> assocRight

      EQ -> case (assoc1, assoc2) of

        -- 2.3.1b
        (LeftAssoc, LeftAssoc) -> assocLeft

        -- 2.3.2b
        (RightAssoc, RightAssoc) -> assocRight

        -- 2.3.3
        _ -> error $ concat
          [ "cannot mix ‘", o1
          , "’ ("
          , show assoc1
          , " "
          , show prec1
          , ") and ‘"
          , o2
          , "’ ("
          , show assoc2
          , " "
          , show prec2
          , ") in the same infix expression"
          ]

      where
        (assoc1, prec1) = opInfo o1
        (assoc2, prec2) = opInfo o2
        assocLeft = Op o2 (Group (reassoc' o1 e1 e2)) e3
        assocRight = Op o1 e1 r

    opInfo op = fromMaybe (notFound op) (Map.lookup op operators) 

    notFound op = error $ concat
      [ "no precedence/associativity defined for ‘"
      , op
      , "’"
      ]
```

Note the recursive call in `assocLeft`: by reassociating the operator applications, we may have revealed another association step, as in a chain of left-associative operator applications like *a* + *b* + *c* + *d* = (((*a* + *b*) + *c*) + *d*).

I insert `Group` constructors in the output for illustration, but they can be removed at this point, since they’re only necessary in the input.

This hasn’t been tested very thoroughly at all, but I think the idea is sound, and should accommodate modifications for more complex situations, even if the code leaves something to be desired.

An alternative that I’ve used is to parse expressions as “flat” sequences of operators applied to terms, and then run a separate parsing pass after name resolution, using e.g. Parsec’s operator precedence parser facility, which would handle these details automatically.